# Pandas inconsistent "Initializing from file failed" with multithreading

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have some code like the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, header=None, parse_dates=[[0,1]])
```

This is called from a watchdog thread. Another process writes the file every minute, and
then the above code gets called through watchdog's "on_modified" and does some processing.
It works a few times and most of the times I get the following traceback:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\App\Lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstr
ap_inner
    self.run()
  File "E:\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\App\lib\site-packages\watchdog-0.8.1-py2.7.eg
g\watchdog\observers\api.py", line 236, in run
    self.dispatch_events(self.event_queue, self.timeout)
  File "E:\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\App\lib\site-packages\watchdog-0.8.1-py2.7.eg
g\watchdog\observers\api.py", line 406, in dispatch_events
    self._dispatch_event(event, watch)
  File "E:\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\App\lib\site-packages\watchdog-0.8.1-py2.7.eg
g\watchdog\observers\api.py", line 401, in _dispatch_event
    handler.dispatch(event)
  File "E:\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\App\lib\site-packages\watchdog-0.8.1-py2.7.eg
g\watchdog\events.py", line 343, in dispatch
    _method_map[event_type](event)
  File "tx_stats.py", line 272, in on_modified
    dur, tail_skip_count)
  File "tx_stats.py", line 209, in read_file
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath, header=None, parse_dates=[[0,1]])
  File "E:\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\App\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.14.1-py2.7-win
32.egg\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 452, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "E:\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\App\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.14.1-py2.7-win
32.egg\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 234, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "E:\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\App\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.14.1-py2.7-win
32.egg\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 542, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "E:\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\App\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.14.1-py2.7-win
32.egg\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 679, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "E:\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\App\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.14.1-py2.7-win
32.egg\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1041, in __init__
    self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "parser.pyx", line 332, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas\par
ser.c:3218)
  File "parser.pyx", line 560, in pandas.parser.TextReader._setup_parser_source
(pandas\parser.c:5608)
IOError: Initializing from file failed
```

What could be wrong? The most puzzling part is that it works some of the time, but not every time. Could it be because of a race condition between this process reading the file and the other process closing the file?

The file contains some statistics like:

```
2014.09.02,00:15,111.7,63,159,134.11261, and so on
2014.09.02,00:16,126.1,08,1235,154.11353,
2014.09.02,00:17,123.5,65,100,153.11313,
2014.09.02,01:18,114.7,59,101,152.11334,
2014.09.02,01:19,111.3,42,1229,153.11283,
```

Comment: This sounds like a very typical behavior for race. You can: 1. implement a lock and see if it stops failing; 2. Check if the file loads correctly in a single-threaded setting

Comment: Yes, I added a locking mechanism and that seems to have solved the problem. Thanks.